# Selfmade WatermarkTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have made a WatermarkTextBox of my own with the following xaml.

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Margin="5 0 5 0"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Foreground="{Binding WatermarkForeground, FallbackValue=#DBDBDB}"
               Text="{Binding Watermark, FallbackValue=This prompt dissappears as you type...}"
               Visibility="{Binding ElementName=txtUserEntry, Path=Text.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    <TextBox Name="txtUserEntry"
             Background="Transparent"
             BorderThickness="0"
             Foreground="{Binding TextForeground, FallbackValue=Black}"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Text="{Binding Text}" />
</Grid>
```

The following code is the code behind which doesn't nee `INotifyPropertyChanged` as far as I know. These `DependencyProperty` should be enough.

```
public String Watermark
{
    get { return (String)GetValue(WatermarkProperty); }
    set { SetValue(WatermarkProperty, value); }
}

public String Text
{
    get { return (String)GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty WatermarkProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("Watermark", typeof(string), 
    typeof(WatermarkTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(""));

public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), 
    typeof(WatermarkTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(""));
```

Then, In my application I use it like this.

```
<c:WatermarkTextBox Watermark="[Design] Name *"
                    Text="{Binding Name, FallbackValue='Name'}" />
```

When I run the application I do see "[Design] Name *" as the Watermark in the TextBlock. Now, in the above example I have the DP `Text` binding to a property `Name` in my ViewModel like this.

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

The ViewModel does implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

A little bit further in my ViewModel, if I press a Button I execute the following code

```
Name = "Test";
```

The word `Test` never wants to show up in the WatermarkTextBox. Even if I type something in it at runtime and request the property `Name` it will still return `null`.

Does this make stuff more clear?

---

I tested the binding with a regular `TextBox`. Here the binding appears to work like it should and does show what it has to. I think the problem is inside my WatermarkTextBox but I would not know where.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, FallbackValue='Name'}" />
```

Comment: Your question makes little sense... you should read it *before* you post it. You said (roughly) 'my control works when I set the `Watermark` property, but not when I set the `Name` property'... why would it do the same thing when you set a different property? What is the relation of your `Name` property to your `Watermark` property?

Comment: Your code and xaml is incomplete, are you trying to create a customcontrol? Could you please post complete code and xaml. I just notice your c:WaterMarkTextBox there. given you are creating a cc, your bindings are wrong in the template, you must [either use findanchestor or TemplateBinding](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf). Your Name auto property (on your vm?) does not update the ui, you must implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Does the WatermarkTextBox also has to include `INotifyPropertyChanged` because the class where I bind the Name to the control implements it?

Comment: @Sheridan, you have to give people time to edit their post when they see a reply. A short reply at my end is faster placed than editing my post and adding more info. Check it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems in your WatermarkTextBox Binding. Assign a name to grid and set its DataContext to UserControl itself because you are binding to the Properties that are in your Control

```
        <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <TextBlock Margin="5 0 5 0"
```

> xaml.cs

```
public partial class WatermarkTextBox  : UserControl
{
    public WatermarkTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        grid.DataContext = this;
    }
```

I hope this will help.

> Update:

```
        <c:WatermarkTextBox Watermark="[Design] Name *"
                Text="{Binding Name,  Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue='Name'}" />
```

Comment: This does fix the problem of not showing the value of the property `Name`. Let say, I set the property to the value "TestCompany". When I change it to "TestCompanyAgain", it will still return "TestCompany". Do you need more code to find why this happens?

Comment: Check when you  set the property whether its Notifying PropertyChanged

Comment: If I set the property `Name`, `NotifyPropertyChanged();` fires. I also set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` for testing purposes. When I change the text in the `TextBox`, `NotifyPropertyChanged();` isn't fired.

Comment: I updated the answer . you need to set Mode=TwoWay in binding of WaterMarkTextBox

Comment: The `Mode=TwoWay` fixed my problem and the problem is now completely fixed. I always assumed it was `TwoWay` by default but appears to be only with certain controls.